# Can players take a "practise" free throw before their "actual" shot?

Tags: rules, officiating, basketball

A player was awarded two free throws on shooting foul. They miss the first and the ball bounces back to them before the referee can grab it.

The player takes a practice shot and then wants the referee to hand him the ball to take a "real" second free throw.

Is this a violation?

Answer (score 2):

The [rules from FIBA](http://www.fiba.com/documents/2015/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf) says:

> 43.2.3. The free-throw shooter shall:
>
> • Take a position behind the free-throw line and inside the semi-circle.
>
> • Use any method to shoot a free throw in such a way that the ball enters the basket from above or the ball touches the ring.
>
> • Release the ball within 5 seconds after it is placed at his disposal by the official.
>
> • Not touch the free-throw line or enter the restricted area until the ball has
>   entered the basket or has touched the ring.
>
> • Not fake a free throw

I don't see any of this leaving room for a "practice" throw, as you can't even fake a free throw. And you have only 5 seconds, so there is not really time for a practice throw any way.

Comment: From my reading, the 5 second count starts only once the ball has been given to the player by an official - if the official never touches it, then I don't see how this can apply.

Comment: @PhilipKendall While that is true the rule is formulated as what is allowed, and throwing a ball in that manner is not mentioned in any way.